# jQuery used to fill browser window regardless of size

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering how this trick is achieved on http://www.vaexu.com/amada.

They have the initial image full screen regardless of the browser window size. I tried to reverse engineer it to see what jQuery is used (what I expect is being used). I know about backstretch but how is the full screen of the div forced?

Has anyone done this technique before? What ways are there of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, they seem to be using bootstrap for the whole visual deal of scrolling (and it going up etc.). But to make an image go 100%, do the following
html;

```
<body>
    <div>
        </img>
    </div>
    ...
```

css;

```
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}
div{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
img{
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for...for some reason I expected it to be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few techniques used here:

1. The container div (v-header-top) is set to 100% (this will take on the full width of its parent)
2. The v-header-top div has a background image applied to it, and it also has the background-size attribute set to cover (background-size: cover)

The result is that the background image scales to the size of its container.